# Group data if the same value with mysql or php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to group the values in one row if they are similar to group them.

Example of the data that I have to group:

```
FG 555  | FRA  |    BRU | 07:00 | 07:50 | 26.Aug.2013
FG 555  | FRA  |    BRU | 07:00 | 07:50 | 2.Sep.2013  
FG 555  | FRA  |    BRU | 07:00 | 07:50 | 9.Sep.2013


BS 444  | MMF  |    TRN | 21:30 | 22:20 | 2.Oct.2013
BS 444  | MMF  |    TRN | 21:30 | 22:20 | 9.Oct.2013    
BS 444  | MMF  |    TRN | 21:30 | 22:20 | 16.Oct.2013   
BS 444  | MMF  |    TRN | 21:30 | 22:20 | 23.Oct.2013
```

Expected result :

```
FG 555  | FRA   | BRU   | 07:00 | 07:50 | 26/Aug/2013 – 09/Sep/2013
BS 444  | MMF   | TRN   | 21:30 | 22:20 | 02/Oct/2013 – 23/Oct/2013
```

Can this be done? Please help me .

thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you a proper answer seeing as you don't give any table or column names, but you want to look at the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Column: FLT_No |  From_D |  To_A | Departure  |   Arrival  |  Date |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MIN` and `MAX` aggregation on dates and format the result with a simple `CONCAT`. You haven't supplied column names, so this example by necessity is generic:

```
SELECT
  Col1Code,
  Col2Code,
  Col3Code,
  StartTime,
  EndTime,
  CONCAT(MIN(DateValue), ' - ', MAX(DateValue))
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY
  Col1Code,
  Col2Code,
  Col3Code,
  StartTime,
  EndTime
```

Comment: SELECT
  `FLT_No`,
  `From_D`,
  `To_A`,
  `Departure`,
  `Arrival`,
  CONCAT(MIN(DateValue), ' - ', MAX(DateValue))
FROM word
GROUP BY 
  `FLT_No`,
  `From_D`,
  `To_A`,
  `Departure`,
  `Arrival`,
LIMIT 0, 30 ;

Comment: i receive this warning:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 300' at line 15

Comment: I think it's the comma after `Arrival`. Try removing that.

Comment: one more think i have another column that contains only numbers from 1 - 7 , so one of them in each row. Now how to group them if the info is the same e.x if the info is the same in 3 different rows ( row1 "1" row2 "5" and row3 "7"  the group to be in one row "157" can this be done ?

Comment: Add a column like this to the `SELECT` list: `GROUP_CONCAT(myNumber ORDER BY myNumber SEPARATOR '')`. The `GROUP_CONCAT` documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). If there can be repeats of your number (for example "11577") and you want to show each number just once ("157"), add the `DISTINCT` keyword: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT myNumber ORDER BY myNumber SEPARATOR '')`.

Answer (score 0):

I use php:

```
 $data = array(
    array("FG 555", "FRA", "BRU", "07:00", "07:50", "26.Aug.2013"),
    array("FG 555", "FRA", "BRU", "07:00", "07:50", "2.Sep.2013"),
    array("BS 444", "MMF", "TRN", "21:30", "22:20", "2.Oct.2013"),
    array("BS 444", "MMF", "TRN", "21:30", "22:20", "9.Oct.2013")
);

$_tmp = array();

foreach($data as $v){
    $_k = md5($v[0].$v[1].$v[2].$v[3].$v[4]);
    if(!isset($_tmp[$_k])){
        $_tmp[$_k] = $v;
        $_tmp[$_k]["min"] = $v[5];
        $_tmp[$_k]["max"] = $v[5];
        continue;
    }

    if(strtotime($v[5]) < strtotime($_tmp[$_k]["min"])) {
        $_tmp[$_k]["min"] = $v[5];
    }

    if(strtotime($v[5]) > strtotime($_tmp[$_k]["max"])) {
        $_tmp[$_k]["min"] = $v[5];
    }
}

var_dump($_tmp);
```

You need foreach $_tmp again to format data.